# I have a Golang application running on Kubernetes, but when the pod dies there are no error message at all. What should I do?

Tags: go, logging, kubernetes

As titled.

When I run `kubectl logs my-go-app-deployment-1967699436-yxxn7` or `kubectl logs my-go-app-deployment-1967699436-yxxn7 -p`, there are no error log print out at all.

What should I do? What makes a Golang pods crashes?

Comment: Please show the manifest that runs your pod and the output of `kubectl describe po <podname>`

Comment: `Please show the manifest that runs your pod` <= my deployment config or what?

Comment: you deployment, yes

Answer (score 0):

First you should inspect the pod to see the reason why it died and if it was restarted.

```
kubectl describe pod my-go-app-deployment-1967699436-yxxn7
```

Look for entries in *Containers -> your container -> Last State*.

If it was restarted you might want to check the previous logs as well:

```
kubectl logs --previous pod my-go-app-deployment-1967699436-yxxn7
```

Comment: Assuming `app-deployment` is the pod name, when I `kubectl describe deployments app-deployment`, it returns `Error from server (NotFound): deployments.extensions "app-deployment" not found`

Comment: The deployment won't contain any errors (or at least it shouldn't). You should describe the pod to see any errors, not the deployment. A deployment is just an object the creates pods (through ReplicaSets). These pods run and may fail. So the pods contain the errors (if any).

Comment: Nothing special when I describe the pod. When I `kubectl logs --previous my-pod` it returns `Error from server (BadRequest): the server rejected our request for an unknown reason (get pods my-pod)`